# Pass function arguments as vector in R

Tags: r, function, vector, arguments

Iam trying to simulate some data in R, therefore I have to pass a lot of parameters to my function(s). I was wondering whether I could store the parameter in a vector and pass them from the vector as arguments.

The idea is:

```
foo <- function(a,b,c)

bar <- c(1,2,3)


foo(bar) == foo(1,2,3)
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `do.call` and pass the input arguments as a `list`

```
do.call(foo, as.list(bar))
```

where

```
foo <- function(a,b,c)  a+ b + c
```